# Java constructor should use setter?

Tags: java, constructor

I have a simple Java model Class called Person which have a constructor that receives a JSONObject. In that constructor I get the values from the JSONObject and put in my instance variables. This is just a simple question but which way is best?

```
public Person(JSONObject personJsonObject) {
    // Without setter
    this.name = personJsonObject.getString("name");
    // With setter passing String
    setName(personJsonObject.getString("name"));
    // With setter passing JSONObject
    setName(personJsonObject);
}
```

And when my setter isn't just a simple attribution but a evaluation, which one should I use?

```
public Person(JSONObject personJsonObject) {
    // Without setter
    this.fullName = personJsonObject.getString("name") + personJsonObject.getString("lastName");
    // With setter passing String
    setFullName(personJsonObject.getString("name"), personJsonObject.getString("lastName"));
    // With setter passing JSONObject
    setFullName(personJsonObject);
    // Or should I put this logic in the getFullName method? The caveat is if there is a huge calculation in the getter method. It wouldn't be efficient.
}
```

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This is a lot about your preference.
What did you choose initially?

Comment: If there is evaluation, I prefer your suggestion:
`setFullName(personJsonObject);`

If you are going to evaluate, accept only what you need, unless it ruins the 'legibility' of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have setter methods (`setName`, `setFullName`) in your class, then your constructor should call the setter methods.

```
setName(personJsonObject.getString("name"));
```

If you don't have setter methods in your class (your class is immutable), then your constructor should perform the evaluation.

```
this.name = personJsonObject.getString("name");
```

You should only pass to a method what it needs.  In this case, your `setName` method takes a String as a parameter, which is what the method needs.  If your method needs 3 or more values from the `personJsonObject` (arbitrary rule of mine), then you would pass the `personJsonObject` to the method.